# Why is the possessive pronoun for "имя" "мое", even though "имя" is a feminine word?

Tags: местоимения

I don't quite understand the reason for why **мое** instead of **моя** is used. Could somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 12):

Имя is a neuter noun, not feminine.

There's a set of similar neuter nouns: имя, вымя, пламя, семя, время, темя, стремя, знамя, племя, бремя etc.

All of them originate from PIE words with the suffix -men. Such words were neuter in PIE as well. In Proto-Slavic, -en and -n̥ became the nasal vowel -ę and later -я.

Thus

> PIE ***e̯neo̯mn*** -> имя
>
> PIE ***see̯mn*** -> семя
>
> PIE ***ĝneo̯mn*** -> знамя
>
> PIE ***bhermn*** -> бремя

etc.

You still can see the -мен- part in oblique cases and the plural: вре**мен**и, вре**мен**ем, вре**мен**а etc, as well as in adjectives: вре**мен**ный, бере**мен**ная.

Answer (score 9):

**Имя** belongs to a special group of 11 nouns ending in **-мя**, all of which are of the *Neuter* gender:

> бремя, время, вымя, знамя, имя, пламя, племя, семя, стремя, темя, голомя

All of them also decline in a special way:

```
       sing.       plur.
_____________________________       
Nom.   врéмя       временá
Gen.   врéмени     времён     (but: семя́н, стремя́н)
Dat.   врéмени     временáм
Acc.   врéмя       временá
Instr. врéменем    временáми
Prep.  врéмени     временáх
```

All the 11 nouns (including **имя**) have the same case endings as **время**, except that:

- **семя** and **стремя** differ slightly in the genitive plural

Comment: Why just 10? You missed бремя, for instance.

Comment: @Anixx - Thank you! They are really 11, no more of them exists in Russian.

Comment: There is also полымя, although it is just native Russian version of пламя.

Comment: There is also письмена which only has plural.

Comment: Ну вот есть ещё одно: рамя https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F

Comment: Also слемя http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/355074

Comment: @Anixx: right, didn't notice it.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion for non-native speakers reading these comments: as a native Russian speaker with a good command of the language, I have no idea what голомя, рамя, or слемя means. So, rest assured, you probably don't need to know either! 

Comment: @il--ya - Boasting about one's ignorance is so Russian.

Comment: @YellowSky Boasting? No. Merely admitting ‍♂️. And labelling people based on their (perceived) nationality is so... unwise?

Comment: @il--ya - Who said “nationality”? Ah, it was you. I'm speaking only about languages here.